# layout messed up for Prince_Productattach module for magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, module, css

I am using a Prince_Productattach module on my Magento 2.3.3 CE, how can I troubleshoot some issues on the frontend.

1. as the diagram shown, the product attach block display on two places, i didn't customize it, how should i find out the reason for this duplicated?
2. The Tab for Download (attachment) on the product detail is the first at the moment, I think normal this tab better put behind, the first should be the product basic information, how can I change the order of the tab on the module?

[image]

Here's the layout catalog_product_view.xml, will you find anything I should adjust to do what mentioned above.

[image]
-- catalog_product_view.xml --

-- end of catalog_product_view.xml --

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit this layout file. See there is a referenceContainer name="alert.urls", and referenceBlock name="product.info.details". Both are using same Block Class Prince\Productattach\Block\Attachment.

referenceContainer name="alert.urls" is using for right side portion.

referenceBlock name="product.info.details" is using for tab.

You can remove or comment any section to hide any section of these two.

Remove all   or  . Then see the change.

Commands to run :

rm -rf pub/static/frontend

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento c:c

Comment: yes, the block unwanted is comment and done.

Comment: do you know how i should change the tab order? make the product_attachment the last and inactive upon page loaded.

Answer (score 1):

The productattachment block can be shown on two places by default. In the XML code you shared there's an `ifconfig` attribute for the `block` nodes which is used to determine if the block should be shown. You don't have to code for these configurations.

The configurations can be found in the admin panel inside `Stores -> Configuration –> Catalog –> Product Attachment –> Configuration`. The first one is named `Show On Product Details`, the second one is `Show On Product Tab`. Just disable the one you don't want to use.

Source: User Guide, available at https://marketplace.magento.com/prince-module-productattachment.html

To change the sort order of tabs you need to add an XML file to your theme applying a `sortOrder` value as a block argument. Add this XML file to your theme (`app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme-code>/Mageprince_Productattach/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="productattach.tab">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">100</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Depending on customisation you already have you may need to set a higher number.

Comment: the code of <argument> for sort_order is perfect. the path to the xml layout file may be different due to version and setup, but the code is definitely working. many thanks.